# find a regular expression for my pattern substring

Tags: python, regex, string

i have a text and i want to extract everything  between two "&HT;". this is a portion of my text:

*&HT;    Several years ago, when Morris Dees of the Southern Poverty Law Center initiated a letter-writing campaign to dissuade bookstore chains and distributors from stocking William Pierce's novel The Turner Diaries,'' much of America thought the KlanWatch founder was overreacting to the violence of a handful of white supremacists.  &HT; Now, with increasing numbers of white males targeting and gunning down members of minority groups, Dees' failed book-banning campaign _ although still unreasonable to most Americans, myself included, on First Amendment grounds _ is not as unpalatable as it once was.  &HT;  The reason is that ``The Turner Diaries'' serves as a bible for killers such as Tim McVeigh and Ben Smith and L.A. day camp shooting suspect Buford Furrow.*

first i wrote `re.findall("&HT;(.*)&HT;",text,re.S)` but this return 1 string that contains text between first &HT; to last &HT;. i realized this problem is caused of this fact that these portions are overlapped and re.findall is for non overlapping matches.
then i used `re.findall("?=T;(.*)&H)")` but in this example text it returns two substrings like this:

*Several years ago, when Morris Dees of the Southern Poverty Law Center initiated a letter-writing campaign to dissuade bookstore chains and distributors from stocking William Pierce's novel The Turner Diaries,'' much of America thought the KlanWatch founder was overreacting to the violence of a handful of white supremacists.  &HT; Now, with increasing numbers of white males targeting and gunning down members of minority groups, Dees' failed book-banning campaign _ although still unreasonable to most Americans, myself included, on First Amendment grounds _ is not as unpalatable as it once was.*

and

*Now, with increasing numbers of white males targeting and gunning down members of minority groups, Dees' failed book-banning campaign _ although still unreasonable to most Americans, myself included, on First Amendment grounds _ is not as unpalatable as it once was.*

how can i get every portion of text placed between two "&HT;" properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `&HT;([^&]+)` see [sample](https://regex101.com/r/2XMmDB/3).

Comment: thanks a lot. i am weak in writing regular expressions. from where can i learn it?

Comment: Also use regexr.com or regex101.com. These are great tools that show you what each token does. That's how i learned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one regular expression `&HT;(.*?)(?=&HT;|$)` in `re.find`.

[Demo](http://regexr.com/3ghvc)